# How do I obtain a complete Ubuntu download?

Tags: downloads

I have a desk top pc on which I would like to install Ubuntu. I am not connected to the Internet and have used public libraries to download Ubuntu onto a USB. But when I try to install onto pc it gets to a point and then asks me to connect to Internet to continue installation. Can I download complete Ubuntu installation and how?

Comment: are you asking about how to pre download  necessary libraries along with Ubuntu setup?

Comment: Yes. you can complete the installation, and you will end up with a full working system. You won't have any daily updates that have been released since the ISO file was created.

Answer (score 2):

There are various types of Ubuntu install media.  The typical ones require the internet to download packages, but there are others where an internet connection is only optional, because the install media is large enough to contain enough packages for a working system.

If the downloaded image file is only a few hundred MB, or less, you probably have a network installer, which requires the internet.

You will want one of the "desktop" ISO images, which are typically around 1.4GB in size.

This is a large initial download but will ensure that you can install a working system even with no internet connection.  It will fit on a DVD or a 2GB+ USB stick.